# UIModalViewController StatusBar background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, statusbar

I set an `UINavigationBar` background tint by `appearance` using macro color:

`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x6DBEE8)];`

And in whole navigation based application but in my `UIModalViewController` does not work:

In my `plist` i have : `View controller-based status bar appearance : YES`

and globally i set `appearance` :     `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];`

Here it what it's look like:
[image]

Comment: Try to change views background color 0x6DBEE8. it's works for me. if i  set view background color to yellow status bar taking yellow color

Comment: The NavigationBar is in the correct color so, i assume changing color will not work.

Comment: i think status bar is not depending on the navigation bar color it depends on the near by view. if status bar is attached to the navigation bar then its taking the status bar color as navigation bar. that my experience.

Comment: Oh, you mean background color, i misunderstood. Yes, you're right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because in iOS7, the height of `UINavigationBar` is increased (64 points) when it is contained in a `UINavigationController`. With the status bar being transparent,when you are presenting a view controller modally, its not in the `UINavigationController` so the height is normal (44 points) and thus the map view is behind the status bar. You need to handle this in your modal view controller. You can:

- Hide the status bar altogether (works but might not be preferable in
  every situation)
- Put a view behind the navigation bar and where the status bar is with
  the same background color.
- Change the color of the view controller's view itself to the desired color and
  offset the y position of your map view to accommodate the status
  bar's height.